# Unable to deploy the SSIS Package into SQL Server 2016

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, ssis-2012, ssis-2016

Currently SSIS package 2012 is working fine in SQL server 2012 so we have migrated the objects into SQL server 2016 and the same package also converted into 2016 and deploying into SQL server 2016 but faced below error.

**Batch File - We dont have dtutil in Program Files for 64 bit :**

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe" /FILE "G:\MSDB2016\MSDB2016\MSDB2016\Package.dtsx" /DestServer <> /COPY SQL;"MISSnOP_Test2016\Package" /Q > test1.txt

**Error - test1.txt :**

Microsoft (R) SQL Server SSIS Package Utilities
Version 11.0.6020.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2012. All rights reserved.

Could not load package "G:\MSDB2016\MSDB2016\MSDB2016\Package.dtsx" because of error 0xC0011008.
Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
Source: Package

**Note :**

The same 2012 package is deployed in SQL server 2016 (MSDB), the SQL job is working fine but not triggered the packages (data is not updated into the audit table). The same package is working fine in manually through VS 2010 and VS 2015. I have tried lot of things but could not resolve this issue.
Please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Like in your prior question, why not use SSISDB?

Comment: I have deployed the same packages in SSISDB ALSO but facing the same issue (job is running fine but package is not triggered and data is not uploaded in the audit table)

Comment: What do the logs say? We need debugging details here.

Comment: Where we need to check the logs? Because package is not triggered that's only

Comment: So how are you starting the package...?

Comment: FYI, that error you've posted if not related to your 2016 instance. `SSIS Package Utilities Version 11.0.6020.0` is for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I have master and child packages so starting the package from master (through MSDB)

Comment: *"through MSDB"* So back to my original question: Why not use SSISDB?

Comment: This is old running package and 36 child packages are there. Here, they are pointing msdb packages through sql server in execute package task editor

Comment: How to change this method

Comment: Moving to SSISDB is not quite, but I strongly suggest you do. It'll take time, and likely a change to how you call your packages (using the Execute Package Task). I suspect the problem is you are trying to launch other packages using SSIS 2012 on your 2016 instance; that won't work. We simply don't have enough information here. Honestly, you'll likely better off hiring someone who knows what they are doing with SSIS.